# External Dlls not getting dropped by TFS

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, tfsbuild

We have a shared build server running TFS2010. We use VS2008 solution(soon planning to upgrade to VS2010) at the moment.

Our ASP.NET 3.5 solution has some external dlls which are placed in our solution's 'Library' folder. Problem is that if we publish the site from our development machine, the the published folder is perfect. But when TFS builds it on the build server, then there are 3 external dlls which never get dropped and we have to manually copy them post build.

We tried a few things but it did not fix the issue. We have also double checked that like other dlls, these 3 dll have the correct refresh files placed in the bin folder.

One problem may be that a few of these problematic dlls may be on the GAC of development machine. If that really is an issue, then on the build server anyway we cannot put dll in the GAC.

Any ideas how we can force these 3 dll to get dropped in the bin folder correctly by TFS?

Answer (score 6):

If you deploy/copy an application that contains a reference to a custom component that is registered in the GAC, the component will not be deployed/copied with the application, regardless of the Copy Local setting. [See MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez524kew.aspx)

You have to force copy local to true by adding **Private** metadata to the GAC assembly reference. Edit your project file and add **Private** metadata:

```
<Reference ..>
    <Private>True</Private>
</Reference ..>

<ProjectReference ..>
    <Private>True</Private>
</ProjectReference ..>
```

Now your GAC assembly should be copied/dropped from the output folder.

Comment: To avoid manual editing, there is a trick: set the reference Copy Local to false and then again to true, and Visual Studio adds the Private metadata automatically. At least VS 2010 does...

Comment: Saved my butt today.  Where's the easy button for getting tfs builds working with nuget and octodeploy.  It works on my machine!!!! Ugh

Comment: If it helps anyone, I recently ran into this issue as well and @JustAMartin's approach still works in VS 2017. Set the reference to Copy Local = `false` then again to `true` and the `Private` node is inserted for you in the project file.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try selecting the dlls from the "References" folder in the Visual Studio solution, then setting Copy Local to true from the properties panel?

Comment: 'Copy Local' is already set to True and the path is set to my Library folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try examining the build log and check if msbuild was able to locate the dll's when building.  You can select diagnostic logging when queuing up the build to get even more detailed logs.